# firefox bug in background-size, with hover and opacity

Tags: firefox, hover, css

I think i found a strange bug in firefox.

When i have an hover class on a div with a background-size property (with a change in the opacity) the size of some of the image a use in the background, changes by one pixel in horizontal, or in vertical.

I made an example of the probleme here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xz4F8/

the html:

```
    <div class="group cont_tutto">
<div class="conteiner_articoli_cinema">
  <div class="back_navigazione_articoli-mag">
    <div class="articolo_mag">
      <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">speciale cinema</div>
      <a href="http://www.google.it">
        <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/16072013/Now-You-See-Me--I-maghi-del-crimine_articolo.jpg')"></div>
        </a>
      <div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="articolo_mag">
<div class="tipo-articoli-mag">speciale cinema</div>
<a href="http://www.google.it">

<div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/16072013/theloneranger384470.jpg')"></div>
</a>
<div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="articolo_mag">
  <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">rcensione fumetti</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.it">
    <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/16072013/Nodo-alla-gola_articolo.jpg')"></div>
    </a>
<div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div></div>
<div class="articolo_mag">
  <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">recensione cinema</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.it">
    <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/15072013/Distribuzione-cinema-e-dvd_articolo.jpg')"></div>
    </a>
  <div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="articolo_mag">
  <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">recensione serie tv</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.it">
    <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/08072013/trueblood-stagione6309717.jpg')"></div>
    </a>
<div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="articolo_mag">
  <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">recensione blu-ray</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.it">
    <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/13072013/ax967523.jpeg')"></div>
    </a>
<div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="articolo_mag">
  <div class="tipo-articoli-mag">recensione cinema</div>
  <a href="http://www.google.it">
    <div class="articolo_mag_cover" style="background-image:url('http://pu2.everyeye.it/public/immagini/12072013/lareligiosa825433.jpg')"></div>
    </a>
 <div class="mag_titolo">
        <h2><a href="/pc/articoli/stealth-bastard-deluxe_recensione_18438" title="Stealth Bastard Deluxe">the lone ranger </a></h2>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


.articolo_mag {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    float: left;
    width: 129px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.articolo_mag_cover {
    width: 129px;
    height: 177px;
    background-size:129px 177px;
    background-color: #333;
}


.articolo_mag_cover:hover {
    background-size:129px 177px;
    opacity: 0.9;}

.mag_titolo {}
.mag_titolo h2 {display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Lato, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;}

.mag_titolo h2:hover {  color: #09F;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;}

.mag_titolo h2 a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 119px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;

}
.tipo-articoli-mag {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    height: 17px;
    width: 115px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Lato, Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 25;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

If i use the cover option for the background-size,the size problems seems attenuated, but, some of the images start to flicker during the update of the page, or the hover state (seems to me, firefox can't decide witch is the right size of the image )

It seems that the problem is triggered by the div container that i use to center all the content in my page (cont_tutto) witch has a 951px in width..

**No problem at all on all the other browsers!**

Answer (score 1):

You had to add "-moz-backface-visibility: hidden" to solve the problem. Here is the solution: http://nickpye.com/2013/04/03/css3-opacity-transition-image-wiggle-bug-in-mozilla-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
transform: rotate(360deg);
```

somewhere as i did to the following image that was moving 1px when hover

```
.btnRoll:hover img {
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have recently experienced the same problem, which is the exact reason I have chosen to stick to the built in "Inspect Element" function in Firefox

- Tanner

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that?